# Spark SCALA - Joining two dataframes where join value in one dataframe is between two fields in the second dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have two dataframes (deleting the fields that are not relevant to the question):

```
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [rawValue: bigint]
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [startLong: bigint, endLong: bigint]
```

I now want to join the two dataframes where:

`rawValue(df1) >= startLong(df2) AND <= endLong(df2)`

Can anyone recommend an efficient way of doing this? The one option I was thinking of was to `flatmap` df2 and then do a straight `join`, but I don't want to do that if there is an efficient way to do the above join.

Answer (score 1):

**You can directly use the condition that you have while joining the two dataframes**

Let me illustrate with an example. I created two `dataframes` identical to the ones you've mentioned

```
val df1 = Seq((2L), (5L), (15L), (9L)).toDF("rawValue")
//df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [rawValue: bigint]

val df2 = Seq((3L, 5L), (10L, 16L), (9L, 9L)).toDF("startLong", "endLong")
//df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [startLong: bigint, endLong: bigint]
```

> > I now want to join the two dataframes where rawValue(df1) >= startLong(df2) AND <= endLong(df2)

For that *you can use the condition* as

```
df1.join(df2, df1("rawValue") >= df2("startLong") && df1("rawValue") <= df2("endLong")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+--------+---------+-------+
|rawValue|startLong|endLong|
+--------+---------+-------+
|5       |3        |5      |
|15      |10       |16     |
|9       |9        |9      |
+--------+---------+-------+
```